# Normalization of colors in a heatmap (with gradient)

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, heatmap, linegraph

Im trying to make a line graph with a heatmap where there will be a gradient between colors, considering the same dates that is showing in the line graph. However, when I include the parameter norm=norm in the final part of the code it the color are solid without gradient (I want the colors will be based on my data_umbral_heatmap values with the gradient)

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#PAQUETES
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
from datetime import datetime as dt
import calendar
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'sctriangulate'])
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------




#INPUTS
ruta=r'C:\Users\buser\OneDrive - BCRP\Escritorio\BASES\Heatmap'
data_umbral_heatmap = [-1.35,-0.65,0,0.65,1.35]


#PROCEDIMIENTO

#1) Obtencion de data
data_indicador = pd.read_excel(ruta+"\data\Final\Indicadores.xlsx",sheet_name = 'BD', header=0)
data_indicador = data_indicador[['Fecha','Sistema']]
data_indicador['Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(data_indicador['Fecha'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()


#2) Formato
# Limites
xmin = data_indicador['Fecha'].min()
xmax = data_indicador['Fecha'].max()
ymin = round(data_indicador['Sistema'].min(),1)
ymax = round(data_indicador['Sistema'].max(),1)




# Queremos que 0 este en el medio del gráfico de color.
if abs(ymax) > abs(ymin):
    lim = abs(ymax)
else:
    lim = abs(ymin)

ax.set_ylim((-lim, lim))
ax.set_xlabel('Fecha')
ax.set_ylabel('Indicador')






#3) Graficando

# Gráfico de linea
data_indicador = data_indicador.set_index('Fecha')
ax.plot(data_indicador.index, data_indicador['Sistema'],'k')
_ = plt.xticks(rotation=90)




# Heatmap (considera epoch: 0=01/01/1970 https://www.unixtimestamp.com/)
xmin=(xmin - dt(1970,1,1)).days #0=01/01/1970
xmax=(xmax - dt(1970,1,1)).days+ 1

data_umbral_heatmap = [-lim] + data_umbral_heatmap +[lim]
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["darkgreen","green","lightgreen","white","yellow",'orange','red'])
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(data_umbral_heatmap, cmap.N)

grad = np.arange(-lim, lim, 2*lim/cmap.N) #-Gradiente va de -lim a lim con N pasos en cmap
grad = np.expand_dims(grad, axis=1)
im = ax.imshow(grad, cmap=cmap, norm=norm,aspect='auto', alpha=1, origin='lower',extent=(xmin, xmax, -lim, lim))
fig.colorbar(im, label='Escalas')
plt.show()
```

I obtained the folowwing graphs, but what I what is that the colors are based in my data_umbral_heatmap values (also I want that the data_umbral_heatmap values will be displayed in the vertical bar of the right side:
[image]

Thanks in advance for everything

Comment: Did you try `norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(data_umbral_heatmap, 256)` instead of `..., cmap.N)`?

Comment: It gives me the same, because the problem is on the line: im = ax.imshow(grad, cmap=cmap, norm=norm,aspect='auto', alpha=1, origin='lower',extent=(xmin, xmax, -lim, lim)). The first graph is obtained removing norm=norm from this line, and the second one with it (like the code)